# How to set fixed size to TextView programmatically?

Tags: android, calendarview

Dears I am trying to create my SimpleCalendarView 
By adding 7 TextViews horizontally in linear layout then repeat it 7 times .. 
But I am facing this issue with the TV's size which changes depending on the it's content
.. could you help me to set suitable size for each TV programmatically 
Or is there best logic to follow ?
Thank you

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.calendar_layout);
    int widthPx = getScreenWidthPx();
    int paddingVal = widthPx/21;
    int paddingVal2 = (int) (widthPx/16.5);
    int paddingVal3 = widthPx/17;

    String weekDays= "M,T,W,T,F,S,S";
    ArrayList<String> weekDaysList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(weekDays.split(",")));
    int dayNumber = 1, newMonthDayNumber = 1; ;
    // set days row in calendar view
    View calendarDaysRow = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.calendar_row, null, false);
    LinearLayout linearLayoutDaysRow = calendarDaysRow.findViewById(R.id.calendar_row);
    for (int i = 1; i <7 ; i++) {
        View dayItem = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.day_layout, null, false);
        TextView dayTV = dayItem.findViewById(R.id.day_tv);
        dayTV.setText(weekDaysList.get(i));
        dayTV.setPadding(paddingVal3,paddingVal,paddingVal3,paddingVal);
        linearLayoutDaysRow.addView(dayTV);
    }
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayoutDaysRow);

    // set month days in calendar view
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        View calendarRow = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.calendar_row, null, false);
        LinearLayout linearLayoutRow = calendarRow.findViewById(R.id.calendar_row);
        for (int i = 1; i <7 ; i++) {
            View dayItem = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                    .inflate(R.layout.day_layout, null, false);
            final TextView dayTV = dayItem.findViewById(R.id.day_tv);
            if (dayNumber < 10) {
                dayTV.setText(String.valueOf(dayNumber++));
                dayTV.setPadding(paddingVal2,paddingVal,paddingVal2,paddingVal);
            }else if (dayNumber > 31){
                dayTV.setText(String.valueOf(newMonthDayNumber++));
                dayTV.setPadding(paddingVal2,paddingVal,paddingVal2,paddingVal);
                dayTV.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            }else {
                dayTV.setText(String.valueOf(dayNumber++));
                dayTV.setPadding(paddingVal,paddingVal,paddingVal,paddingVal);
            }
            dayTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String text = dayTV.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            linearLayoutRow.addView(dayTV);
        }
        linearLayout.addView(linearLayoutRow);
    }
}

private int getScreenWidthPx (){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}
}
```

day.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:text="20"
android:maxLines="1"
android:id="@+id/day_tv"
android:background="@drawable/day_back_ground"/>
```

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/calendar_row"/>
```

[image]

Comment: you can use layout weight so that each box has fixed size and fill up the space

Comment: thank you for your reply ,, but that is already what I've did .. I've updated my question with xml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use textview attribute "ems" like
`android:ems`

sets the width of a TextView to fit a text of n 'M' letters regardless of the actual text extension and text size.

Answer (score 0):

You need a scalable size unit which helps to support multiple screens.

- [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp): The replacement for `dp` and `dip` (for views)
- [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp): The replacement for `sp` (for texts)

Comment: thank you for your reply ,, but my issue is not with multi screens .. I am still trying in the same screen but the TextViews are not the same width ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this depedency to handle to all dp and sp : 
**implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'** 
and use in the xml like this:- android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp" also in the java/ kotlin file like this R.dimen._100sdp.
and progrmatically use this :-  txtView.setTextSize(R.dimen._18sdp);

Comment: thank you for your reply ,, but my issue is not with multi screens .. I am still trying in the same screen but the TextViews are not the same width ..